# Enable wifi hardware switch using software

Tags: debian, laptop

On Debian 9.7, 4.9.0-8-amd64

On my laptop I want to enable my wireless card. Laptop keyboard connector (locking clip) is missing so I can't use it's keyboard enable the hardware switch.

Already did

```
sudo rfkill unblock all

2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

`firmware-atheros` drivers are already installed. Card is a Qualcomm Atheros AR9287.

I already checked my laptop if there are any hardware switches around (external,internal), nope.

I tried using a USB keyboard and emulate Fn + F3 (wifi switch) and was unsuccessful.

Although upon using the Debian installer, I was able to use wifi upon selecting it as my primary network interface (with internet) although it does not adopt to be the default network interface after the installation.

Is there anything else I could do to enable my wireless card?

**To clarify I just want to replicate how the Debian installer enabled my laptop's wireless adapter without the laptop's keyboard wifi hardware switch.**

Comment: You won't fix a missing hardware switch by software

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of a wifi hardware switch that you could turn on by software. It would sort of defeat the whole purpose of having a hardware switch in the first place.

So I see you have a couple of options:

- Turn on the wifi and leave it turned on. This will probably involve a screwdriver. Possibly changing the keyboard to one where the switch is working. You can then turn it off by software (which you are clearly aware of).
- Use a USB wifi netcard.

Having a USB wifi netcard has saved my ass multiple times, so I can highly recommend you get a USB wifi netcard, that does not require additional drivers - even if you choose not to use it in this case.

Comment: Short circuiting the connectors where the switch was, cutting the pin of the WiFi chipset that disables it... Google is your friend.

Comment: ... Or if you are lucky, the switch is no more there, but the barrel it pushes still is. It pays off being inventive and curious a little